# Is it possible to combine ggMargin plots using patchwork in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I generated a couple of  plots in R and attached a x-axis histogram using ggMargin (from  package). When I tried to combine those plots using , I get the following answer: "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Combining already combined graphs works when I use only pathwork

Is there a (easy) way how I could combine these graphs? Or do I have to make the histogramms and the geom_point plots separately and in the end combine everything with "patchwork"?
Thnx in advance!

#Here is some test code to replicate the problem:

````
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
library(patchwork)

col_pH <- runif(n = 100, min = 5, max = 8)
col_abund <- runif(n=100, min = 0, max = 5.5)
col_SOC <- runif(n=100, min = 0.5, max = 3.6)

testplot1 <- ggplot(testdata, aes(x=col_pH, 
                              y=col_abund))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

margin_testplot1 <- ggMarginal(testplot1, 
                        type = "histogram", 
                        bins = 16, 
                        margins = "x")

testplot2 <- ggplot(testdata, aes(x=col_SOC, 
                                  y=col_abund))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

margin_testplot2 <- ggMarginal(testplot2, 
                               type = "histogram", 
                               bins = 16, 
                               margins = "x")

testplot1/testplot2 #works
X <- testplot1/testplot2
X|testplot1 #works
margin_testplot1/margin_testplot2 #Error in margin_testplot1/margin_testplot2non-numeric argument to binary operator```
````

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to wrap your marginal plots in `patchwork::wrap_elements`:

```
library(patchwork)

wrap_elements(margin_testplot1) / wrap_elements(margin_testplot2)
```

[image]